# In Visual C++/C#, can I compile a program such that it doesn't show a message box if it crashes?

Tags: c#, visual-c++

Is it possible to compile a C#/C++ program with Visual C#/C++ compiler such that if it crashes, it doesn't show a message box (I don't mind if it writes output to console or even asks for user input - but only through the console).

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as a C#/C++ compiler.  In a C# program you can subscribe the AppDomain.UnhandledException event and call Environment.Exit() in the event handler.  In a C++ program you can call SetUnhandledExceptionFilter() and call TerminateProcess() in the callback.  Check the MSDN docs, this is all well documented.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event and call  [Environment.Exit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx) method in handler and you won't see any message.

Answer (score 0):

A c# program shows a message showing the exception which made it crash.

If you surronund the main function of your program in a try catch, and close the program "gracefully", you'll see no box.

Pehaps in C++ you can apply the same technique.